# What does the term sophistry mean today?

Tags: meaning, language-evolution, argument-structure

Does the term sophistry as it is used today demand intentional deception or does it also include well-crafted arguments based on faulty assumptions or the use of flawed reasoning?

I just glanced at Merriam-Webster.com and dictionary.com and they didn't define sophistry as an attempted deception, although MW characterized it as the use of subtly deceptive reasoning, which I guess does include the implication of intentional attempt to make someone believe that which is known to be false. However, the initial definitions at both sites didn't include that element and focused more on the fact that the arguments were false. I guess I am wondering how you gauge typical meaning now.

Comment: I think “*as it is used today*” needs elaboration.  The dictionary still says *deceptive* and that’s how I use it today.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - well I could change it to say, “All the dictionaries Edwin looked in still say...” but I’m past the five-minute point. ;-)

Comment: Being "creative" with the definition of sophistry is merely practicing "good" sophistry.

Comment: @Jim 'in the dictionary ...' is taboo on ELU. It's lacking attribution and implies that there is a consensus, when the writer has rarely bothered to check in more than one or two dictionaries.

Comment: I just glanced at Merriam-Webster.com and dictionary.com and they didn't include define sophistry as an attempted deception, although MW characterized it as the use of subtly deceptive reasoning, which I guess does include the implication of intentional attempt to make someone believe that which is known to be false. However, the initial definitions at both sites didn't include that element and focused more on the fact that the arguments were false. I guess I am wondering how you gauge typical meaning now.

Answer (score 2):

The [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sophistry) definition:

> **sophistry** [MASS NOUN]
>
> 1 The use of clever but false arguments, especially with the intention
>   of deceiving:
>
> *trying to argue that I had benefited in any way from the disaster was pure sophistry*

obviously allows for false arguments **not** 'intended to deceive' (and thus not recognised as false by their proponents).

However, ODO indicates that the intent to deceive is present in the default sense, which is the only sense given by some respected dictionaries.